# Get the value of a html div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello guys I'm trying to get the value of a div in javascript but it seems like it doesn't work. As you can see the traffic light in front of "Share Checks" is red, and that's because "Shared filters" is red, and this traffic light shall only be green if all the traffic lights are green but when i run for example "Shared Dashboards" the traffic light becomes green even if i put in my if statement that it can only be green if it wasn't red previously. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJJ5j.png)

```
<div class="float-child"> <div id="ShareChecksStatus"> </div> </div>
```

i tried this:  `var filter = $('#ShareChecksStatus').html();`

and also this:  `var filter =  document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML;`

this where i give my div a value:

```
if (value.securityCheckName== "ShareFilter" && value.checkStatus == "SUCCESS" && $('#ShareChecksStatus').text() !== "<span>&#128308;</span>)" ){
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#128994;</span>";
        
    }
     else if(value.securityCheckName== "ShareFilter" && value.checkStatus == "FAILED" ) {
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#128308;</span>";
    }
     else if (value.securityCheckName== "ShareFilter" && value.checkStatus == "RUNNING"){
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#9898;</span>";
     }

     else if (value.securityCheckName== "ShareDashboard" && value.checkStatus == "SUCCESS" &&  $('#ShareChecksStatus').text()  !== "<span>&#128308;</span> )"){
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#128994;</span>";

    }
     else if(value.securityCheckName== "ShareDashboard" && value.checkStatus == "FAILED") {
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#128308;</span>";
    }
     else if (value.securityCheckName== "ShareDashboard" && value.checkStatus == "RUNNING" ){
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#9898;</span>";
     }
    
    //Shareobj
     else if (value.securityCheckName== "ShareObject" && value.checkStatus == "SUCCESS"  &&  $('#ShareChecksStatus').text() !== "<span>&#128308;</span> )"){
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#128994;</span>";

    }
     else if(value.securityCheckName== "ShareObject" && value.checkStatus == "FAILED") {
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#128308;</span>";
    }
     else if (value.securityCheckName== "ShareObject" && value.checkStatus == "RUNNING" ){
        document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#9898;</span>";
     }

    }
```

it just seems like my third condition in my if statement gets ignored no matter how i write it...

Comment: Please post the whole code.

Comment: can you please elaborate the question? can you post a sample demo and your desired output of that code.

Comment: Do you have any error in Console?

Comment: No errors are found

Comment: I see in your code that you put `(` inside of ` !== "<span>&#128308;</span>)"`, is your mistake just in question or do you have same typo in your source code?

Comment: i checked and the source code is fine actually

Comment: `.text()` will *never* === `"<span>..` because .text() removes html elements and returns... well.. the text (only).  Use `.html() !==`  also:  **debug your checks** - add a line: `console.log($('#ShareChecksStatus').text())` to see what you're *actually* getting so that you know if your comparison makes sense.

Comment: Please include a **complete** snippet - see [mcve].  You use `$("#ShareChecksStatus")` but your image has 3 lines, so it's unclear which one you're referring to as IDs must be unique.

Comment: Please also clarify exactly what you're asking as the question appears to relate to *setting* the innerHTML, but your comments state that the `var =` is not getting the value - but then, not getting the value you're *trying* to assign it - the `var =` part seems to be unrelated to the actual issue.  (using `.text()` instead of `.html()` as commented above).

Comment: eg your first line is *I'm trying to get the value of a div* - but the issue is that you're not *setting* it.  Please be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, it seems to work fine, so maybe your error is somewhere else (I just removed `(` from `"<span>&#128308;</span> )"`, because I believe it's a typo).

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML;

if (document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML !== "<span>&#128308;</span>" )
{
   document.getElementById('ShareChecksStatus').innerHTML = "<span>&#128994;</span>";
        
}
```

```html
<div class="float-child"> <div id="ShareChecksStatus"> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because of the conditions that you check, the code inside the brackets do not run , try setting div value before the checks

Comment: I really appreciate your help, It would be easy for OP if you could add some code that rectify the problem of OP. This will increase the change of `upvote` and `acceptance of answer`. 

Answer (score 0):

Check if the condition is getting satisfied.
You can use $('#ShareChecksStatus').text() to access the div content